# QNetworkAccessManager how to check whether there is pending request?

Tags: c++, qt

In qt4.8, where there is still the qhttp class, I could use `http->hasPendingRequests()` to check whether there is still pending requests.
But in qt5, we are forced to use the QNetworkAccessManager class to manage the http link.
How could I achieve this checking?

Comment: Use the returned QNetworkRequest and call isRunning() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#isRunning

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never, although I could not find related docs, try something like:

```
QNetworkAccessManager myManager;

// Some requests here...

QList<QNetworkReply *> list =
    myManager.findChildren<QNetworkReply *>();
```

> **Note** that above is only tested with Qt4 and Qt5 (but might be true for coming versions),
> And actually, this is how Qt itself finds them for destruction.